# AWS API Gateway Resource ID mapping with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I've a module of `AWS API Gateway` which were created by `Terraform`, Gateway creating without any issues, however when I tried to create a nested `api gateway resource`, the resources are taking a wrong `ID`, it suppose to take a parent ID, but instead it somehow takes an `ID` of different parent, seems it takes by alphabetical order.

---

Here the code it self:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "parent" {
   for_each    = { for key, value in var.restapi.resource : key => value }
   path_part   = lookup(each.value, "path", null)
   parent_id   = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.managed : value.root_resource_id ], each.key)
   rest_api_id = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.managed : value.id ], each.key)
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "childs" {
   for_each    = { for key, value in var.restapi.resource.childs : key => value }
   depends_on  = [ aws_api_gateway_resource.parent ]
   path_part   = lookup(each.value, "path", null)
   parent_id   = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.managed : value.id ], each.key)
   rest_api_id = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.managed : value.id ], each.key)
}
```

---

The problem in `aws_api_gateway_resource. childs` is `parent_id`, as I mentioned above it takes wrong parent `ID`, here the `terraform plan` result:

```
# module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.parent["1"] will be created
+ resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "parent" {
    + id          = (known after apply)
    + parent_id   = "j3pt41ko7f"
    + path        = (known after apply)
    + path_part   = "saml-store"
    + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
  }

# module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.childs["1"] will be created
+ resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "childs" {
    + id          = (known after apply)
    + parent_id   = (known after apply)
    + path        = (known after apply)
    + path_part   = "saml-store/enable"
    + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
  }

# module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.childs["2"] will be created
+ resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "childs" {
    + id          = (known after apply)
    + parent_id   = "b72571"
    + path        = (known after apply)
    + path_part   = "block/disable"
    + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
  }
```

---

`module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.childs["2"]` taking a wrong `ID`, it should take the same `ID` of `module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.childs["1"]`, which is unknown and will be known only after `apply`, so the `path_part` for `module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_resource.childs["2"]` must be "saml-store/enable" instead of "block/disable", how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is `var.restapi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you use a `data` statement [Data Source: aws_api_gateway_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/api_gateway_resource), here you can exactly specify the `path` according to your code, it will be the solution, at the end it will return the exact id

```
data "aws_api_gateway_resource" "my_resource" {
  rest_api_id = "your_rest_api_id"
  path        = "/endpoint/path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a copy-paste issue in your child resource (you are referencing managed instead of parent):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "childs" {
   for_each    = { for key, value in var.restapi.resource.childs : key => value }
   depends_on  = [ aws_api_gateway_resource.parent ]
   path_part   = lookup(each.value, "path", null)
   parent_id   = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.managed : value.id ], each.key)
   rest_api_id = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.managed : value.id ], each.key)
}
```

You should change it to:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "childs" {
   for_each    = { for key, value in var.restapi.resource.childs : key => value }
   depends_on  = [ aws_api_gateway_resource.parent ]
   path_part   = lookup(each.value, "path", null)
   parent_id   = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.parent : value.id ], each.key)
   rest_api_id = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.managed : value.id ], each.key)
}
```

Comment: Hello, @Nick I've made a typo mistake while coping the code here;
--
element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.parent : value.id ], each.key)
--
The parent ID is `element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.parent : value.id ], each.key)`